# ElasticSearch Date Histogram Interval

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

Why my query contain filter from date, to date, but when use date histogram aggregation, start interval out of from date to date range(sometimes).
My query filter from `2015-01-01` to `2015-01-31`, interval start date must be in range `2015-01-01` to `2015-01-31`, but start date my result is `2014-12-31`. How can I define start date in range `2015-01-01` to `2015-01-31`.
[image: date histogram]

My full query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "cluster": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cluster"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "histogram_Log": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "actionTime",
            "interval": "1800m",
            "format": "dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "typelog": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "typeLog"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match_all": {}
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "actionTime": {
                        "lte": "2015-01-31T00:00:00.000",
                        "gte": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following format with `HH` instead. You're using `hh` which are on a 12-hours scale instead of 24-hours scale.

```
   "format": "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
```

**UPDATE**

Given your interval of `1800m`, you also need to specify this offset

```
   "offset": "1d"
```

Comment: it only effect on data format result. I need start date interval in range from date to date, if i change range a year(2015-01-01 to 2015-12-31), start date interval will be 2014-12-21.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't clear from the example you gave, but I still find it difficult to believe that you get dates outside the specified range. Any reason why you have a `30h`(i.e. `1800m`) interval?

Comment: I need 24 part of days in range from date to date(24 interval)

Comment: Can you fix the format as I suggested and then show again an example of a query and results that don't match your expectation?

Comment: i don't know why if I choose n days divisible 24, all interval part of days will be in fromdate todate range, else, interval start date out of range.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the latest query and results?

Comment: Can you try one more thing, please? Add this as a sibling to the `typelogs` sub-aggregation: `"docs":{"top_hits":{"size":10,"_source":["actionTime"]}}`. I'd like to see what dates we have in that first bucket.

Comment: Thanks, any chance to see all the hits? Feel free to copy/paste instead of attaching an image.

Comment: all hit in range >=2015-01-01

Comment: One thing I don't see in those dates, though, is the timezone!! Hence those dates might be local to your timezone, while the bucketing is done according to GMT by default. Can you specify a `time_zone` in your date_histogram?

Comment: Thanks Val, please update your answer, specify time_zome resolve my problem, i will vote you.

Comment: i has try, but something, start `interval` out of range date between min & max `extended_bounds`, something true, `offset` just only add specify date of start date, my problem is: get total log in 1 week, interval must be 24 part(7h/interval): 2015-01-01 00:00:00 , 2015-01-01 07:00:00,...,2015-01-06 10:00:00 , 2015-01-06 17:00:00. But something, start date out of range 2015-01-01 00:00:00 to 2015-01-07 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp you have highlighted in your result is not the timestamp of a document, it is the start of your first bucket.

Your first bucket goes from 31/12/2014 00:00:00 to 01/01/2015 06:00:00.

You have filtered your query to only return documents with a timestamp later than 01/01/2015 00:00:00, but since that is before 01/01/2015 06:00:00 you have documents that fall into your first bucket.

If you want to also force your buckets to start at 01/01/2015 00:00:00 then you will need to specify it as the `extended_bounds.min` in the histogram aggregation.

Comment: Thanks Fowler , I forgot specify time_zone

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you question Code.I solve it.I delete some code form your template code.so I did this code for work.this is very easy template for "date_histogram => date range" is ok

```
       var queryOptions = 
            {
       "aggs": {
         "all_hours": {
             "date_histogram": {
               "field": "stamp",
               "interval": "1d",
               "format": "dd/MM/YYYY"
                         }
                     }
             },
            "query": {
       "filtered": {
       "filter": {
           "bool": {
             "must": [
               {
                 "bool": {
                   "must": [
                     {
                       "match_all": {}
                     },
                     {
                       "range": {
                         "stamp": {
                           "lte": "2016-10-20",
                           "gte": "2016-05-01"
                         }
                       }
                     }
                   ]
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
         }
      }
   }
  }
`
```